# Title command will not appear (1.13)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to make a system that essentially displays a title to those who enter a certain area, and a different those who exit that same area. The problem is that, despite the fact that the command I'm using has the right syntax (`scoreboard players add @a[x=-54,z=-21,dx=-59,dz=59] inSpawn 1`, which then triggers `title @a[scores={inSpawn=..1}] title {"text":"Safezone","color":"green"}`), the title won't show up.

The command block I'm using for the `title` command says the title was shown, but I'm not getting anything. I've attempted messing with score values, changing coordinates, even using *both* commands outside of a command block, but it still won't show. Nothing I've found, or at least, that I have access to view in normal search results, have given me anything useful.

Comment: Obvious question: Did you check if you have the right score?

Comment: Yup, and as I said before, the command block *and* chat when I used it said that it had displayed the title... but that never happened.

Comment: What happens if you replace the title command with "say test"? What happens when you instead remove the selector argument?

Comment: I... it's working? I don't know what to do about this question now, but it suddenly started working after I rejoined the realm. This apparently has happened to others the more I look at it.

Comment: I do have another question that I believe could be answered here. Should I just make a new question, or can you help out out quickly? I don't want to question-spam the website

Comment: Well, you could self-answer that it now randomly works, I guess. Well knows, maybe one day another person has the same problem and the same solution works for them. About the new question: Yes, you should create a new one. There are currently 86000 questions on gamingSE, one more would be "spam". ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For some reason, restarting the game seems to have worked.** I'm unaware of what caused the issue to begin with, but once I rejoined the game it worked perfectly.